# beamer babel devanagari and sans serif engish

Tags: beamer, babel

I'm trying to setup a base document producing slides with a devanagari script language as 'main' and some english. My problem is that i'm not getting latin letters in sans serif font. Here i declared hindi as main and english with \babelprovide. Could someone explain how the 2 following instances of \babelfont will assign the given font to either hindi or english?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{babel}

\babelprovide[mapdigits,maparabic,import,main]{hindi}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts]{english}
\babelfont{sf}{chandas}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{FreeSerif}
\defaultfontfeatures{Renderer=Harfbuzz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{प्राथमिकी}
आम्रः

\foreignlanguage{english}{this text in english}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Chandas isn’t a sans font. You can add something like `\babelfont[english]{sf}{FreeSans}`.

Comment: You can also use `serif` font-theme with `\usefonttheme{serif}`.

Comment: @Niranjan I'd need your answer in context. I did not even know that my \babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{FreeSerif} was affecting chandas

Comment: @JavierBezos does \babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{FreeSerif} do something useful here?

Comment: Only if a serif font (ie, `\rmfamily`) is used in the document. Just remove it and see what happens. If everything is fine, then it’s not necessary.

Comment: `babelfont` takes a language(s) option: `\babelfont{sf}{Shobhika}` defines sf font for all languages; `\babelfont[english]{sf}{Latin Modern Sans}` defines sf English font only, to be Latin Modern Sans.

Answer (score 1):

The default `beamer` setup uses sans theme for fonts. One is supposed to explicitly change the theme to serif when using serif fonts. The following example uses package `fontspec` with XeLaTeX to produce the result you want. This is one way of doing what you want. I am sure there will be various other ways to do it. I am demonstrating the way I prefer.

```
% !TeX program=xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{serif}% Comment this when using Sans-fonts.
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage{babel}
\babelprovide[maparabic,import,main]{hindi}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Chandas}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{प्राथमिकी}{यह पाठ्य देवनागरी लिपि में लिखा है।}
देवदत्तः आम्रफलं खादति।

\foreignlanguage{english}{This text is in English}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1]